# Spring Boot Unit Test @Value from .properties File gives NullPointerException

Tags: spring-boot, junit, spring-boot-test, spring-junit

I am trying to read a value from a properties file for a unit test case in Spring Boot. I have two `config.properties` files, one in `src/main/resources`:

```java
prop = some-value
```

and one in `src/test/resources`:

```java
prop = some-test-value
```

Main Application class:

```java
package company.division.project;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "company.division.project")
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:config.properties")
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        System.setProperty("DUMMY_PROPERTY", "dummy-value");

        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Do nothing with main
    }
}
```

Service class to be tested:

```java
package company.division.project.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Service {
    @Autowired
    Environment environment;

    public String getProperty() {
        return environment.getProperty("prop");
    }

}
```

ServiceTest class. I have tried two approaches to retrieving the value in the `src/test/resources/config.properties` file; one with an `@Autowired Environment`, and one with an  `@Value` annotation...neither worked:

```java
package company.division.project.service;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@TestPropertySource("classpath:config.properties")
public class ServiceTest {
    @InjectMocks
    Service service;

    @Autowired
    Environment environment;

    @Value("${prop}")
    private String expectedProperty;

    @Test
    public void testGetPropertyWithValueAnnotation() {
        assertEquals(expectedProperty, service.getProperty());
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetPropertyWithEnvironment() {
        assertEquals(environment.getProperty("prop"), service.getProperty());
    }
}
```

I read somewhere on StackOverflow, that in order to auto-wire components in a Spring test class, I'll need to create an entire context for the test, so I tried this (change the annotations and test runner):

```java
package company.division.project.service;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;


@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class ServiceTest {
    @InjectMocks
    Service service;

    @Autowired
    Environment environment;

    @Value("${prop}")
    private String expectedProperty;

    @Test
    public void testGetPropertyWithValueAnnotation() {
        assertEquals(expectedProperty, service.getProperty());
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetPropertyWithEnvironment() {
        assertEquals(environment.getProperty("prop"), service.getProperty());
    }
}
```

The context was created, but both approaches ended in `NullPointerException`s once again.

Comment: `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` won't work. What is the exact exception message?

Comment: This is the error message (in every case):

`java.lang.NullPointerException
 at company.division.project.service.ServiceTest.testGetPropertyWithValueAnnotation(ServiceTest.java:34)`

Comment: Why won't `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @shazin's answer and some of my own research I've been able to solve the problem.

Basically, there needs to be compatibility between the test runner class specified in `@RunWith` and the annotations for the Mockito mocks. We want to test the `Service` class:

**Service Class**:

```java
@Component
public class Service {
    @Autowired
    Environment environment;

    public String getProperty() {
        return environment.getProperty("prop");
    }
}
```

If you're using `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)`, you can use the `@InjectMocks` and `@Mock` annotations like below. Whatever is `@Autowired` in `Service` will be auto-wired with the mocks:

**Test Class with `MockitoJUnitRunner`**:

```java
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ServiceTest {
    @InjectMocks
    Service service;
        @Mock
        Environment mockEnvironment;

    @Before
    public void before() {
        Mockito.when(mockEnvironment.getProperty("prop")).thenReturn("some-test-value")
    }
}
```

But you can't auto-wire anything ***in the test class itself***. That requires a Spring Context (a Spring Context is needed to manage the beans which get auto-wired into objects). That's where `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` comes into the picture. You can use it to run a test case with a dedicated Spring context (you'll notice the test case logs showing a new Spring application being booted up for every test class with the `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` annotation). You'll also need to provide the Configuration details with the `@SpringBootTest` annotation.

The caveat is that a test class with `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` won't understand the `@InjectMocks` and `@Mock` annotations; you'll have to use the `@MockBean` annotation. This will effectively modify the Spring context by replacing beans with their mocks; anything with the `@Autowired` annotation will get auto-wired with the mock beans automatically:

**Test Class with `SpringRunner`**:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes=Application.class)
public class ServiceTest {
    @Autowired
    Service service;

    @MockBean
    Environment mockEnvironment;

    @Before
    public void before() {
        Mockito.when(mockEnvironment.getProperty("prop")).thenReturn("some-test-value")
    }
}
```

So...using the `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` didn't achieve anything  except change the names of the annotations (`@InjectMocks` -> `@Autowired`, and `@Mock` -> `@MockBean`), right? Wrong. Using `SpringRunner` gives you the power of auto-wiring components ***within your test case***. So if you want to use an actual `Environment` (not a mock one), you can do that as well; just auto-wire it in from the dedicated Spring context:

**Test Class with `SpringRunner` and `@Autowired` Environment**:

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes=Application.class)
public class ServiceTest {
    @Autowired
    Service service;

    @Autowired
    Environment environment;

    @Test
    public void testServiceGetProperty() {
        assertEquals(environment.getProperty("prop"), service.getProperty("prop");
    }

}
```

And that solves the problem.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your test is that you are trying to use to `MockitoJUnitRunner.class` in a wrong way.

If you are mocking a Service using `@InjectMocks` you need to make sure you need to return the value `Service.getProperty()` by mocking the service call. If you are using `SpringRunner.class` then you shouldn't have `@InjectMocks` but should have `@Autowired` for the service. Following test works.

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class ServiceTest {
    @Autowired
    Service service;

    @Autowired
    Environment environment;

    @Value("${prop}")
    private String expectedProperty;

    @Test
    public void testGetPropertyWithValueAnnotation() {
        assertEquals(expectedProperty, service.getProperty());
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetPropertyWithEnvironment() {
        assertEquals(environment.getProperty("prop"), service.getProperty());
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly on the minimal example I posted here, but when I try it on my original code, it gives me an `IllegalStateException: Unable to find a @SpringBootConfiguration`. Any ideas?

Comment: @shinvu `@SpringBootTest` searches for the class annotated by `@SpringBootApplication.`. You can either give your main class explicitly by `@SpringBootTest(classes=YourMainClass.class)`, or putting your test in the same or child pacakge of your SpringBootApplication annotated class.

Comment: @helospak Perfect! Adding the main class explicitly worked. Thanks.